# How can I get image from Open Flash Chart 2?

Tags: javascript, charts

I have tried this [tutorial](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/adv-upload-image.php), but that doesn't work at all. My server side is working ok, but when I try to get instance of ofc and call post_image, Firefox gives following error "ofc.post_image is not a function". Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Its hard to help you because you haven't shown what you've done. Post some of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and i solved it just updating open-flash-chart.swf for the Kvasir version one (previously i was using Jörmungandr version). It seems like the old version was corrupted and does not allow the access to AS external functions. I needed also to clear cache data and cookies on my browser (firefox) in order to take the new swf. I've got a new problem with getting flash chart 2 image, the data is uploaded to my server and the png is saved on file system but the callback function for post_image is never triggered, my code is similar to ofc2 site samples:

```
function done(id){
alert("Finished upload. Id:"+id);}

function post_chart_image(chart_png_name){
url =  context + '/swtMktShare/uploadChartImage.html?chartImgFileName='+chart_png_name;
var ofc = findSWF("my_chart1");
x = ofc.post_image( url, 'done', false);}
```

On the server side i'm using Spring MVC and as response i get the full path of the png generated file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while trying the tutorial. In the line:

```
x = ofc.post_image( url, 'done', debug );
```

I was getting this error on the browser: `Object doesn't support this property or method`.

I found the problem in these lines:

```
function findSWF(movieName) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!= -1) {
        return window[movieName];
    } else {
        return document[movieName];
    }   
}
```

In the if check it was returning `return window[movieName]` in my case, as my browser is IE8.

I just removed the if check and just used `return document[movieName]`:

```
function findSWF(movieName) {
    return document[movieName]; 
}
```

That solved my problem and I am able to save the charts as images now.